# Get inner most values in the Map as a List in `Map<String, List<Map<String,Map<String,String>>>>` Java

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I need to get the values in the inner most map as a list in `Map<String, List<Map<String,Map<String,String>>>>`.

Other than for each, Can we implement it using streams?

Comment: did you try implementing it? can you share your attempt?

Comment: As I can see, the description changed from keys to values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream#flatMap returns a Stream of all values of all elements:

```
List<String> converted = yourComplexStructure.values().stream()
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .map(Map::values)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream())
    .map(Map::values)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It takes the values of your structure as a Stream, maps it to a Stream with all elements of each List, maps it to a Stream with all values of the Maps, creates a Stream with all values of the most inner maps and collects it.

---

<sup>Note that it is basically the same as the other answer (we wrote it at the same time) but I changed this answer so that it doesn't require lambdas but uses method references.</sup>

Comment: The title and the description of the question contradict. This doesn't solve for "*I need to get the key values in the inner most map as a list..*"

Comment: Sorry for that. I basically need help in getting the values in the inner map, which belongs to a particular key..

Comment: Is it possible to get the values, which belong to a particular key ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

```
    List<String> keys = map.values().stream() // get the first list
            .flatMap(List::stream) //flatten the list
            .flatMap(mapOfMap -> mapOfMap.values().stream()) //get the list of all values
            .flatMap(mapOfMap -> mapOfMap.keySet().stream()) //get the keys
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As [@dan1st](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62569772/427321) pointed out, [flatMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) is key to success here.

To get the values you simply change the innermost flatMap:

```
    List<String> values = map.values().stream() // get the first list
            .flatMap(List::stream) //flatten the list
            .flatMap(mapOfMap -> mapOfMap.values().stream()) //get the list of all values
            .flatMap(mapOfMap -> mapOfMap.values().stream()) //get the values
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

To filter for a key:

```
List<String> values = map.values().stream() // get the first list
                .flatMap(List::stream) //flatten the list
                .flatMap(mapOfMap -> mapOfMap.values().stream()) //get the list of all values
                .flatMap(mapOfMap -> mapOfMap.entrySet().stream()) //get the entries (key -> value)
                .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals("somekey")) //filter here
                .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Is it possible to get for a particular key ?

Comment: of the innermost map? sure. you need to filter the entries for that key. see edit.